# how to delete data in influxdb2.0?

Tags: java, influxdb

how to delete data in influxdb2.0, how to delete in springboot project?
I use influxDBClient, it has a api calls getDeleteApi(), but I don't know
how to use it , DeleteApi.delete(@Nonnull final DeletePredicateRequest predicate,
@Nonnull final String bucket,
@Nonnull final String org)

in my project , I can user InfluxDBUtil to delete a meansurement's data